# I have create an sessionStorage array and have assigned values as shown here. labe

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, session-storage, sessionstorage

I have created a sessionStorage array named labe and assigned some values as shown below.
labe[25,36,42]
My key value is labe and I want to change the value from 36 to 87 in sessionStorage itself. How can I do that the same in javascript?

Comment: You should add more details. It is impossible to see what you're actually asking.

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: The title should give a short summary and not contain the complete problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sessionStorage only saves data in string, so when you write something like `sessionStorage.setItem('labe', [25,36,42])`, `[26, 36, 42]` will be converted to string `'25,36,42'` before stored in sessionStorage. That means, you just cannot save an object directly to sessionStorage, or localStorage.

Usually, we do it like this:

`sessionStorage.setItem('labe', JSON.stringify([25,36,42]))`

and get it back:

`var labe = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('labe'))`.

Then `labe` become an array again, so you just change `labe[1]` from **36** to **38**, and save it again:

`sessionStorage.setItem('labe', JSON.stringify(labe))`.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The link below would really help you a lot, please do check it out.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp

However, this should do the trick.

`sessionStorage.setItem("labe", [25, 87,42]]);`